# how do I stop FutureBuilder method called twice

Tags: flutter, dart

I will create a post method to with dio library

```dart
  Future<dynamic> postData(
      String id, String firstName, String lastName, String department) async {
    final response = await dio.post(
      url,
      data: {
        "id": id,
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName,
        "department": department
      },
    );
    return response.data;
  }
```

the FutureBuilder method call the first time I work correctly but it automatically call again
so it trey to post again the same id so it cost the error

```dart
Future<void> main() async 
{
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget 
{
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) 
  {
    final UserRepository _userRepository = UserRepository();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _userRepository.postData("33", "sj", "tt", "it"),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print("FutureBuilder builder method called"); // Debug print
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) 
            {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) 
            {
              print('1');
              print("Data received: ${snapshot.data.toString()}");
              // Debug print
              print('2');
              return Center(child: Text(snapshot.data.toString()));
              print('3');
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) 
            {
              String errorMessage = snapshot.error.toString();
              print("Error occurred: $errorMessage"); // Debug print
              return Center(child: Text("Error: $errorMessage"));
            } else 
            {
              print("Unknown error occurred"); // Debug print
              return const Center(child: Text("Unknown error occurred"));
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I try to debug with print
hear is what I got

```dart
debug console
I/flutter (12062): FutureBuilder builder method called
Reloaded 1 of 825 libraries in 393ms (compile: 34 ms, reload: 155 ms, reassemble: 132 ms).
I/flutter (12062): FutureBuilder builder method called
I/flutter (12062): 1
I/flutter (12062): Data received: {id: 33, firstName: sj, lastName: tt, department: it}
I/flutter (12062): 2
D/EGL_emulation(12062): app_time_stats: avg=5496.77ms min=25.07ms max=10968.47ms count=2
Restarted application in 992ms.
2
I/flutter (12062): FutureBuilder builder method called
I/flutter (12062): 1
I/flutter (12062): Data received: Error: Insert failed, duplicate id
```

the FutureBuilder builder method called again and again until it got error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `StatelessWidget` into a `StatefulWidget` and assign your future only once on the `initState` method:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late final Future _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final UserRepository _userRepository = UserRepository();
    _future = _userRepository.postData("33", "sj", "tt", "it");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _future,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Text(snapshot.data);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: now to stop throw error but it still call twice

Comment: I/flutter (12062): FutureBuilder builder method called
I/flutter (12062): 1
I/flutter (12062): Data received: {id: 37, firstName: sj, lastName: tt, department: it}
I/flutter (12062): 2
Reloaded 1 of 825 libraries in 393ms (compile: 42 ms, reload: 183 ms, reassemble: 110 ms).
D/EGL_emulation(12062): app_time_stats: avg=26543.67ms min=37.71ms max=53049.62ms count=2
Restarted application in 31,544ms.
2
I/flutter (12062): FutureBuilder builder method called
I/flutter (12062): 1
I/flutter (12062): Data received: {id: 38, firstName: sj, lastName: tt, department: it}
debug console

Comment: Every time you restart the application, the layout of your application will be built again. As consequence, the `build` method of your `MyApp` will be called again. Since your `FutureBuilder` is directly inside the widget tree, the `postData` will be called again. If you want it to be called only once (even when restarting the application), you should put it into a button, so it will only be called when the user presses it.

Comment: If you can provide some information on what you're trying to accomplish, I can help you better.